# How to set text to UILabel from Button click in different views

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi everyone iam new in objective c, now i try to create the app like ["What's the word"](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/whats-word-new-quiz-pics-word/id573511269?mt=8). I find this [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/77981/make-letter-word-game-uikit-swift-part-1)  and lerned it as well as i can. But i have some problems. I want when i click on buttons the currentTitle replace the lable in placesView. Button click method in LettersView.m named as "displayChar". I have success in getting currentTitle but now i don't know how to pass it to GameController and paste text on "places". 
I will be grateful for any help!

Here is my code

**LettersView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class LettersView;
@protocol LetterClickDelegateProtocol <NSObject>
-(void)letterView:(LettersView*)letterView addChar:(NSString *)addChar;
@end

@interface LettersView : UIImageView

@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly) NSString* letter;
@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL isMatched;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *clickLetter;

@property (weak, nonatomic) id<LetterClickDelegateProtocol> clickDelegate;

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *lblChar;

-(instancetype)initWithLetter:(NSString*)letter andSideLength:(float)sideLength;

@end
```

**LettersView.m**

```
#import "LettersView.h"
#import "config.h"

@implementation LettersView{
    NSInteger _xOffset, _yOffset;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    NSAssert(NO, @"Use initWithLetter:andSideLength instead");
    return nil;
}

-(instancetype)initWithLetter:(NSString*)letter andSideLength:(float)sideLength
{
    //the letter background
    UIImage* img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_letter@2x.png"];

    //create a new object
    self = [super initWithImage:img];

    if (self != nil) {

        //resize the letters
        float scale = sideLength/img.size.width;
        self.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,img.size.width*scale, img.size.height*scale);

        UIButton *lblChar = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
        lblChar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        lblChar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [lblChar setTitle:letter forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [lblChar addTarget:self action:@selector(displaychar:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self addSubview:lblChar];

        self.isMatched = NO;

        _letter = letter;
        self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)displayChar:(id)sender {
    UIButton *lblChar = (UIButton *)sender;
    NSLog(@" The button's title is %@.",  lblChar.currentTitle);
    _clickLetter = lblChar.currentTitle;
    if (self.clickDelegate) {
        [self.clickDelegate letterView:self addChar:lblChar.currentTitle];
    }
    NSLog(@"hu %@", _clickLetter);
}
```

**PlacesView.h**

```
//  PlacesView.m
#import "PlacesView.h"
#import "config.h"

@implementation PlacesView

-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    NSAssert(NO, @"Use initwithletter");
    return nil;
}
-(instancetype)initWithLetter:(NSString *)letter andSideLength:(float)sideLength
{
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_input@2x.png"];
    self = [super initWithImage: img];

    if (self != nil) {
        self.isMatched = NO;

        float scale = sideLength/img.size.width;
        self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, img.size.width*scale, img.size.height*scale);

        //bullshit time
        _fieldForLetter = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
        _fieldForLetter.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        _fieldForLetter.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        _fieldForLetter.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        _fieldForLetter.text = @"*"; // if button pressed button title placed here. 
        [self addSubview:_fieldForLetter];
        _letter = letter;
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

**GameController.m**

```
#import "GameController.h"
#import "config.h"
#import "LettersView.h"
#import "PlacesView.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation GameController {

    //tile lists
    NSMutableArray* _letters;
    NSMutableArray* _places;

}

-(instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        self.points = [[PointsController alloc] init];
        self.audioController = [[AudioController alloc] init];
        [self.audioController preloadAudioEffects: kAudioEffectFiles];

    }

    return self;
}


-(void)dealRandomWord {

    NSAssert(self.level.words, @"Level not loaded");

    // random word from plist
    NSInteger randomIndex = arc4random()%[self.level.words count];
    NSArray* anaPair = self.level.words[ randomIndex ];


    NSString* word1 = anaPair[1]; // answer
    NSString* word2 = anaPair[2]; // some letters
    _helpstr = anaPair[3]; // helper

    NSLog(@"qweqweq %@ %@" , word1 , word2);

    NSInteger word1len = [word1 length];
    NSInteger word2len = [word2 length];

    NSLog(@"phrase1[%li]: %@", (long)word1len, word1);
    NSLog(@"phrase2[%li]: %@", (long)word2len, word2);

    //calculate the letter size
    float letterSide = ceilf( kScreenWidth*0.9 / (float)MAX(word1len, word2len) ) - kTileMargin;

    //get the left margin for first letter
    float xOffset = (kScreenWidth - MAX(word1len, word2len) * (letterSide + kTileMargin))/2;

    //adjust for letter center
    xOffset += letterSide/2;
    float yOffset = 1.5* letterSide;


//    init places list
    _places = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: word1len];

// create places
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i<word1len; i++){
        NSString *letter = [word1 substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];


        if (![letter isEqualToString:@" "]) {
            PlacesView* place = [[PlacesView alloc] initWithLetter:letter andSideLength:letterSide];
            place.center = CGPointMake(xOffset + i*(letterSide + kTileMargin), kScreenHeight/4);


            [self.gameView addSubview:place];
            [_places addObject: place];
        }
    }

    //init letters list
    _letters = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: word2len];

    //create letter
    for (NSInteger i=0;i<word2len;i++) {
        NSString* letter = [word2 substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];


        if (![letter isEqualToString:@" "]) {
            LettersView* letv = [[LettersView alloc] initWithLetter:letter andSideLength:letterSide];
            letv.center = CGPointMake(xOffset + i * (letterSide + kTileMargin), kScreenHeight); // "/3*4"
            if (i > 6) {
                letv.center = CGPointMake(-5.15 * xOffset + i * (letterSide + kTileMargin), kScreenHeight + yOffset); // "/3*4"
            }
            letv.clickDelegate = self;

            [self.gameView addSubview:letv];
            [_letters addObject: letter];
        }
    }

}

-(void)letterView:(LettersView *)letterView addChar:(NSString *)addChar
{
    PlacesView* placesView = nil;

    for (PlacesView* pl in _places) {
        //if (CGRectContainsPoint(pl.frame, pt)) {
        if () {
            //placesView = pl;
            placesView.fieldForLetter.text = letterView.lblChar.currentTitle;

            break;
        }
    }
    //1 check if target was found
    if (placesView!=nil) {

        //2 check if letter matches
        if ([placesView.letter isEqualToString: letterView.letter]) {
            [self placeLetter:letterView atTarget:placesView];
             [self.audioController playEffect: kSoundLetterTap];

            self.points.points += self.level.coinsPerLvl; //ne nado tak

            NSLog(@"Current points %d" , self.points.points);

             [self checkForSuccess];
        } else {
            [self.audioController playEffect:kSoundFail];
            [self addAlert:@"ne success" andMessage:@"You lose!" andButton:@"eshe cyka"];
        }
    }
}
-(void)placeLetter:(LettersView*)letterView atTarget:(PlacesView*)placeView {
    placeView.isMatched = YES;
    letterView.isMatched = YES;

    letterView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
}

-(void)checkForSuccess {
    for (PlacesView* p in _places) {
        //no success, bail out
        if (p.isMatched==NO) return;
    }
    NSLog(@"ya!");
    [self addAlert:@"Success" andMessage:@"You win!" andButton:@"eshe cyka"];
    [self.audioController playEffect:kSoundSuccess];
}

-(void)addAlert: (NSString *)addTitle andMessage: (NSString *)alertMessage andButton: (NSString *)alertButton {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        UIWindow* window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];

        window.rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
        window.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert + 1;
        UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle: addTitle message:alertMessage preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        UIAlertAction *defaultAction= [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:alertButton style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {

            window.hidden = YES;

        }];
        [alert addAction:defaultAction];
        [window makeKeyAndVisible];
        [window.rootViewController presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
        });
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `GameController` needs to keep a reference to `PlacesView`. It can also assign the action into `LettersView` so when the button in `LettersView` is pressed, the `GameController` will fetch it and perform an action in `PlacesView`. `GameController` is what both the other classes have in common, so it can handle any actions between them.

Another option is to use [NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/) and post a message in `LettersView` when the button is pressed, and listen for it in `PlacesView`.

Yet anther way is using a [delegates](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html) where `GameController` makes sure that `PlacesView` is set as the delegate. When `LettersView`'s button is pressed, it will call the delegate method which `PlacesView` listens to.

I'd go with first option.

Comment: Thanks for help your advice was very useful for me!